# How to get getIntent().getExtras() to work in a fragment, 'getIntent is undefined for the type'

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi i'm trying to change an activity to a fragment so i can add it to a swipe layout and i think i'm just about done (unless anyone can see any other errors in my code) but i cannot find a solution to my problem anywhere, it says that 'getIntent() is undefined for the type SoftwarePageFragment' I'm really new to this and have literally been coding in android to a week or so???

```
   package com.learn2crack.tab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
   /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}
public class SoftwarePageFragment extends Fragment implements OnHeadlineSelectedListener {




    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.rooms_view, container, false);


    //@Override
    //public void onStart() {
      //  super.onStart();

        if (getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return container;
            }

            // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key", value);//you can use putInt or putBoolean etc
            firstFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

        // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
        ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Software);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

        } else {
            // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
        final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
        int mCurrentPosition = -1;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
            // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
            // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
            }

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sofware_view, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
            // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
            // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
            // below that sets the article text.
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            if (args != null) {
                // Set article based on argument passed in
                updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
            } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
                // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
                updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
            }
        }

        public void updateArticleView(int position) {
            TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Software);
            article.setText(Rooms[position]);
            mCurrentPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
            outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
        }
    }

    public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
        OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;




        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
            int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

            // Create an array adapter for the list view, using the Ipsum headlines array
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Software));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
            // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Software) != null) {
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
            // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
            try {
                mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Notify the parent activity of selected item
            mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

            // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;




    static String Software[] = {
            "3D Studio Max 2014",
            "Adobe Creative Suite 6",
            "Agilent Agent",
            "Android SDK",
            "Audacity",
            "C Map Tools",
            "Cedar and Easy 68k",
            "Context",
            "CryEngine 3",
            "Derive V5.0",
            "Dreamweaver CS6",
            "Eclipse",
            "Face Modeller",
            "Flash CS6",
            "Image J",
            "Linux",
            "Matlab R2012A (Computing Toolbase)",
            "Matlab R2012A (Maths)",
            "Microsoft Project",
            "Microsoft SQL Sever Lite",
            "MinecraftEDU",
            "MiniTab 16",
            "MonoGame",
            "NetBeans 7.3.1",
            "Office 2013",
            "Oracle Client",
            "Photoshop CS6",
            "Premiere CS6",
            "Python 3.3.2",
            "QT 5.1",
            "R-Studio",
            "Rational Architect",
            "Steam",
            "SWI Pro Log",
            "Unreal UDK",
            "Visio 2012",
            "Visual Studio 2012",
            "Win A&D 7 Desktop",
            "Windows Mobile SDK",
            "Weka ML",
            "XNA Game Studio"};

   static  String Rooms []= { "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",
            "MEA 27\n MEA 34\n",




    };



}
```

Answer (score 15):

Use getActivity() in Fragment like this:

```
Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
String value= args.getString("key");
```

Comment: that seems to have worked for the bit but now there a problem with this 

 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return container;
            }

it says 'savedInstanceState cannot be resolved to a variable' and the same error for container

Comment: try this: `@Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString("key", value);

    }`

Answer (score 3):

try

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", value);//you can use putInt or putBoolean etc
firstFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: That didnt work it just gave me red lines everywhere

Comment: I'm getting an error with key saying 'invalid character constant'

Comment: you may change `'key'` to `"key"`

Comment: It now says 'value cannot be resolved to a variable'

Answer (score 2):

`getIntent()` is a method of `Activity`, so you can not use inside a `Fragment` since a fragment do not usually deal with `Intent`. You should use setArguments/getArguments pair to pass data from the `Activity` to the `Fragment`

Comment: How would you do that ?

Answer (score 2):

send like this

```
Fragment createNewChildForDir(int index, String machineId, int lvl) {
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    if (args == null) {
        args = new Bundle();
    } else {
        args = new Bundle(args);
    }
    args.putString("machineId", machineId);
    args.putString("hash_key", getDir[index].did);
    args.putInt("lvl", lvl);
    args.putString("isretrived", "yes");

    Fragment f = new ChildrenMakingActivity();
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

and recive like this

```
machineId = args.getString("machineId");
            hash_key = args.getString("hash_key");
            isretrived = args.getString("isretrived");

            lvl = args.getInt("lvl",0);
```

Comment: i want to send int index, String machineId, int lvl u can pass any which u want then just replace fragment as usual

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with `Bundle Extras` instead of `getIntent()` like this :

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String temp = args.getString("key");
```

Comment: That gives me reds lines throughout the entire if statement. where about's would i put that ?

Comment: all of the if statement, i cant write it on here its too long, but i got rid of firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras()); and put in your suggestion

Comment: No thats not the issue

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key", value);//you can use putInt or putBoolean etc
            firstFragment.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: Check your value data type and put values into bundle according to that.

Comment: sorry to sound stupid, but i've only been doing this for a week how do you do that?